# Unresolved symbol only in 32bit mode (RtlCaptureStackBackTrace)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, dynamic-linking

I'm building a DLL that makes use of CaptureStackBackTrace. In 64bit mode everything builds fine while 32bit mode yields a linking error:

"**error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RtlCaptureStackBackTrace referenced...**"

This is a function declared in winnt.h and defined in kernel32.dll, so I have hard time understanding why this happens. I'm building using VS2015 Update 3 - I have been building the exact same code just fine in the past so I'm somewhat suspecting that some compiler changes or Windows SDK paths may be involved but it's not easy to verify this.

Help please! :)

Comment: I think this was a Bug in an Update. Update to the latest Version and Test again please.

Comment: Please compare properties of your project for 32 bit and 64 bit, you may get some hint.

Comment: Sadly, updating to KB3165756 didn't resolve the issue. My project/solution files are generated and I'm certain it isn't related.

I'll try to find a PC with VS2015 that isn't updated yet and see how it behaves....

Comment: Did you try to link against the [libraries described in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552119(v=vs.85).aspx) (NtosKrnl.lib)

Comment: @PeterT No, but that doesn't prevent 64bit build from linking fine. This function is in DLLs that are loaded with every process - I doubt this is the reason - I'll give it a try once yet-another-update finishes installing.

Comment: But it doesn't complain at runtime it complains at link-time. That the dll being loaded at runtime means that you can get the function via GetProcAddress at runtime it doesn't help you at link-time. The by-default linked libs might differ between the Win32 and x64 presets.

Comment: Small update: code builds fine with VS2012 - later VS versions are ok but only if using v110 (VS2012) toolset. 

@PeterT I cannot use LoadLibrary/GetModuleHandle/GetProcAddress in this particular case :(

Comment: I didn't say `use GetProcAddress`. I said "the dll being loaded at runtime only means that GetProcAddress should work". Did linking explicitly with `NtosKrnl.lib` not help?

Comment: @PeterT NtosKrnl.lib doesn't exist on my computer (with VS 2012, 2013 and 2015 installed)

Comment: @mtosic it should be part of the windows SDK. Usually VS2015 installs the a windows sdk (by default into "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits"). In the Windows 10 SDK it's "OneCoreUAP.lib" for the usermode version.

Comment: Normally that file should be automatically linked if you selected a Platform/PlatformVersion that could use that function. What are the values for those two things for you [in the project properties](http://imgur.com/QT8mWrP.jpg)?

Comment: Ok, clearly I need better explanation of all these settings - v140 is fine if I use 'Target Platform Version' 10.0.xxxxx as then it links against OneCoreUAP as you suggested. Leaving that setting at 8.1 does not work.

However, I'd like my software to work on older than 10 versions of Windows, and it doesn't seem to me that choosing 10.0.xxx is the way to go in this case...

If there's any page clearly explaining relationships between all these settings I'd LOVE to see it.

Comment: I tried on another machine where I have Visual Studio 2015 Community edition - everything works fine even with v140. I can only think that I have a faulty installation on the PC where I have this problem. I do have 3 versions of VS there, along with a number of SDKs for different platforms... It's quite difficult to see what went wrong.